# How can I install python-dev package in a computer without internet?

Tags: python, unix

I couldn't find 'python-dev' package anywhere. I don't have the luxury to find it via pip or yum, since I don't have internet connection on my computer. I need to locate the 'python-dev' source, download it, and install it in my computer without internet and sudo access.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I am confused. If you don't have internet access how are you going to download it?

Comment: `python-dev` (probably) contains the Python header files. I don't think you'll find that using `pip`. What OS are you on?

Comment: Which OS is the target machine running?

Comment: maybe get the url and download the package onto a PC that has internet, save it to a flash drive, then copy package back to the other PC that doesn't have internet, using [How do I find package URLs with Yum?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85715/how-do-i-find-package-urls-with-yum)

Comment: I'm running OpenSUSE Unix

Comment: here's a link to download the "Source Package" https://opensuse.pkgs.org/42.2/opensuse-oss/python-devel-2.7.12-24.1.x86_64.rpm.html

Comment: @downshift, sorry to bother you again but that site doesn't have instructions on how to install it without root access. In addition, the package seems to be for Python2.7, but I need it for Python3.6. Thanks!

Comment: No worries, have you seen this https://superuser.com/questions/431347/how-can-i-install-python-dev-without-sudo

Answer (score 1):

`python-dev` contains everything you need to build Python extensions. So, it will typically include the `Python.h` header file, and probably some Python shared object files to link with.

If you have a compiler on the target machine, you can probably build that yourself by looking at how `python-dev` does it for various operating systems.

Comment: Source for reference please? I couldn't find anything on google search about how to build python-dev from source...

Comment: If you compile Python from source, you should get everything you need from there, but it may not be packaged for you the way you need it.